# set extra data with templateSelection

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

When i search it works fine with all text id and logo , but now i want to add default data , i am able to add text and id with Option but not the logo

so how do i add extra data which comes from array , i tired adding logo in options with $(options).data but that also did not worked

```js
var d = [{
  "text": "I Like It",
  "id": "427818",
  "logo": "https:\/\/cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax\/libs/simple-icons\/3.2.0\/pandora.svg"
}, {
  "text": "71. I Like It (feat. Kontra K and AK Ausserkontrolle)",
  "id": "146387",
  "logo": "https:\/\/cdnjs.cloudflare.com\/ajax/libs\/simple-icons\/3.2.0\/deezer.svg"
}];

searchfocussongs(d);

function searchfocussongs(data) {

  var apiurl = "";
  var curartistid = "";

  $("#sm_report_focussongs").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    width: 'resolve',
    templateResult: searchfocussongs_template,
    templateSelection: searchfocussongs_template,
    ajax: {
      url: apiurl + "?f=searchSmSongs&aid=" + curartistid,
      dataType: "json",
      type: "GET",
      processResults: function(data) {
        //console.log(data);
        return {
          results: $.map(data, function(item) {
            return {
              text: item.text,
              id: item.id,
              logo: item.logo
            }
          })
        };
      }
    }
  });

  if (data.length > 0) {

    $(data).each(function() {
      var option = new Option(this.text, this.id, true, true);
      $(option).data('logo', this.logo);
      $("#sm_report_focussongs").append(option).trigger('change');
    });

    $("#sm_report_focussongs").trigger({
      type: 'select2:select',
      params: {
        data: data
      }
    });
  }
}

function searchfocussongs_template(ar) {
  var item = $(
    '<span><img src="' + ar.logo + '"  style="height:20px;width:20px;" /> ' + ar.text + '</span>'
  );
  return item;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<select class="form-control" multiple="multiple" id="sm_report_focussongs" style="width:100%">
```

Comment: You're using `ar.logo` in your `searchfocussongs_template` function but from where it is coming from? In your function you need to add `$(option).data('logo', this.logo);`

Comment: @mandy8055 i added that but still it does not show the logo 
      $(data).each(function () {
        var option = new Option(this.text, this.id, true, true);
        $(option).data('logo', this.logo);
        $("#sm_report_focussongs").append(option).trigger('change');
      });

Comment: @CBroe processResults is working fine when data is coming from ajax 
it also display logo  text properly 
the issue is with default data (var d) it does not display logo as you can see  when you run the code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a full demo covering also the search scenario. To achieve that I redefined the `$.ajax` function that when called with `http://bogusendpoint/` returns a mock ajax response with a filtered set of songs according to the search parameters.

In my first answer I went quick and dirty and didn't address that so the given solution didn't take into account the fact that the callback function was called in different scenarios having different conditions. As you pointed out in the comments, it was appropriate to check if 'state.logo` is undefined and in that case fetch the data attribute instead.

```js
//list of real logo names from siple-icons
const logos = [ "spotify", "pandora", "deezer", "apple", "tidal", "youtube", "amazon", "soundcloud" ];

//list of real songs titles
const songTitles = [ "Imagine", "One", "Billie Jean", "Bohemian Rhapsody", "Hey Jude", "Like a Rolling Stone", "I Can't Stop Loving You", "Sweet Child o' Mine", "Under Pressure", "Hotel California", "Thriller", "Stairway to Heaven", "Shake it Off", "Halo", "Happy", "Despacito", "Shape of You", "Roar", "Jump", "Smooth Criminal" ];

function getRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

//create a list of 50 {id,text,logo,artistId} made up from thin air
let songsArray = Array.from({length: 50}).map(() => ({
  id: getRandom(100000, 999999),
  text: songTitles[getRandom(0, songTitles.length - 1)],
  logo: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-icons/3.2.0/${logos[getRandom(0, logos.length - 1)]}.svg`,
  artistId: getRandom(1, 10)
}));

//filter the songsArray returning the subset matching artistId exact number and term as a word contained in .text
function filterSongs(songsArray, term, artistId) {
    return songsArray.filter(song =>
        song.text.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()) &&
        (artistId == '' || song.artistId === artistId)
    );
}

//redefine the $.ajax function...
(function ($) {
    var originalAjax = $.ajax;
    $.ajax = function (params) {
        //listening to the url http://bogusendpoint/
        if (params.url.indexOf('http://bogusendpoint/') === 0) {

            //support for GET params populating the keyValues properties bag
            var queryString = params.url.split('?')[1];
            var keyValues = {};
            if (queryString) {
                queryString.split('&').forEach(function (pair) {
                    var keyValue = pair.split('=');
                    keyValues[keyValue[0]] = decodeURIComponent(keyValue[1]);
                });
            }

            //query will contain both params.data and the querystring keyValues
            const query = {...keyValues, ...params.data};

            let results = [];

            //if the f param is searchSmSongs
            if('f' in query && query.f === 'searchSmSongs'){
                //grab the query terms from the request
                let searchParam_q = '';
                let searchParam_artistId = '';
                if ('q' in query) searchParam_q = query.q;
                if ('aid' in query) searchParam_artistId = query.aid;
                //filter the songs full set
                const filteredSongs =
                  filterSongs(songsArray, searchParam_q, searchParam_artistId);
                //and prepare a response object with the filtered set
                results = filteredSongs;
            }

            //resolve and return the "promise"
            var deferred = $.Deferred();
            deferred.resolve(results);
            if (params.success) params.success(results);
            return deferred.promise();
        }

        //if the endpoint differs, call and return the original ajax function
        return originalAjax.apply($, arguments);
    }

})(jQuery);

//init the select2
const apiurl = 'http://bogusendpoint/'
const artistId = '';
$("#sm_report_focussongs").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    width: 'resolve',
    templateResult: searchfocussongs_template,
    templateSelection: searchfocussongs_template,
    ajax: {
        url: `${apiurl}`,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        data: function(params) {
            return { f: 'searchSmSongs', aid: artistId, q: params.term };
        },
        processResults: function(data) {
            return {
              results: data.map(item => (
                { text: item.text, id: item.id, logo: item.logo }
              ))
            }
        }
    }
});

const baseurl = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-icons/3.2.0/';
var staticSongs = [
    { text: 'I Like It', id: 427818, logo: `${baseurl}/pandora.svg` },
    {
      text: '71. I Like It (feat. Kontra K and AK Ausserkontrolle)',
      id: 146387,
      logo: `${baseurl}/deezer.svg`
    }
];
addAndSelectSongs(staticSongs);

function addAndSelectSongs(songs){
    songs.forEach((song) => {
        var option = new Option(song.text, song.id, true, true);
        $(option).data('logo', song.logo);
        $("#sm_report_focussongs").append(option).trigger('change');
        $("#sm_report_focussongs")
          .trigger({ type: 'select2:select', params: {data: song} });
    });
}

function searchfocussongs_template(state){
    if (!state.id) {
        return state.text;
    }

    let logoSrc = state.logo;
    if(!state.logo)
        logoSrc = $(state.element).data('logo');
    
    return $(`<span><img src="${logoSrc}" style="height:20px;width:20px;" />${state.text}</span>`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select
    id="sm_report_focussongs"
    class="form-control"
    multiple="multiple"
    style="width:100%"></select>
```

### Quick & Dirty solution - using a data attribute for the logo src

Since you have not the `.logo` property in the `ar` argument passed to `searchfocussongs_template`, you may use a data attribute of any target `<option>` element that can be retrieved at any time later and in that specific context doing `ar.element`.

Here is a stripped down example that will focus on that specific issue:

```js
var d = [
    {
        "text": "I Like It",
        "id": "427818",
        "logo": "https:\/\/cdnjs.cloudflare.com\/ajax\/libs/simple-icons\/3.2.0\/pandora.svg"
    },
    {
        "text": "71. I Like It (feat. Kontra K and AK Ausserkontrolle)",
        "id": "146387",
        "logo": "https:\/\/cdnjs.cloudflare.com\/ajax/libs\/simple-icons\/3.2.0\/deezer.svg"
    }
];

searchfocussongs(d);

function searchfocussongs(data) {
    if (data.length > 0) {
        $(data).each(function() {
            //you are creating an option element saying defaultSelected=true and selected=true for all of them!
            var option = new Option(this.text, this.id, true, true);
            //setting the data-logo attribute for the new option element
            $(option).data('logo', this.logo);
            $("#sm_report_focussongs").append(option).trigger('change');
        });
    }

    $("#sm_report_focussongs").select2({
        minimumInputLength: 2,
        width: 'resolve',
        templateResult: searchfocussongs_template,
        templateSelection: searchfocussongs_template,
    });
}

function searchfocussongs_template(ar) {
  //and I'm fetching the logo data retrieving the information from ar.element through its data attribute value
  var item =
    $(
      '<span><img src="' + $(ar.element).data('logo') +
      '"  style="height:20px;width:20px;" /> ' + ar.text + '</span>'
    );
  return item;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<select class="form-control" multiple="multiple" id="sm_report_focussongs" style="width:100%">
```

Comment: yes it works , but not for the processresults but i understood why it did not work 

here is what i did 

 function searchfocussongs_template(ar) {
    var logo = "";
    if (typeof ar.logo == 'undefined'){
      logo = $(ar.element).data('logo');

    }else{
      logo = ar.logo;

    }

    var item = $(
      '<span><img src="' + logo + '"  style="height:20px;width:20px;" /> ' + ar.text + '</span>'
    );
    return item;
  }

Comment: @skcrpk I understand what you are saying and now I took the time to correctly address the full scenario and include also the search feature. You already had the exact solution but it was fun for me to deal with the ajax mock response and it was worth the effort